# How can I automatically suggest the language for my Wordpress website based on the location?

Tags: wordpress

I want my Site to be available in different languages, so when a visitor stops by, he automatically reads his language.

The Plugin should be free and easy to install :)

Comment: Most translation plugins have an option to detect the browser language. Like Polylang which is free, or WPML, TranslatePress... all of them.

Comment: did Polylang helped?

Answer (score 0):

[Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) is a great free and open-source WordPress plugin which allows you to create a bilingual or multilingual WordPress site. It detects the system language and will automatically switch to that language.

[image]